# Check mail sent with mail command

Tags: email, debian, mail-server

I've got a Debian mail server, and I use the mail command to send confirmation e-mails when users register our website. Is there any way to view a list of the mails that were sent?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.  Add a `Bcc` ("blind carbon copy") header to all your generated mails containing a special technical address, say, `generated-mails`, then add an entry for it to the system aliases table, like this:

```
generated-mails: "| /usr/local/bin/process-generated-message"
```

where the `/usr/local/bin/process-generated-message` should be an executable program which expects the message on its standard input and does with it whatever it wants.

Alternatively, you can just append these messages to a file:

```
generated-mails: /var/local/spool/generated-mails
```

(Note that this file must be writable by the user (and/or group) which `postfix` on your system uses when it's delivering mails locally — this is OS-dependent.)

The details are explained [here](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html).

I recommend using `Bcc` header field (and not `Cc`) as it gets stripped off from the message when it's being sent do the actual recipients, so they don't see this cruft in their messages.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The problem was that I needed to retrieve a log from mails sent in the past (before a measure like the one you described above was taken). I'll be adding this feature in the future though.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found out there are some records in the /var/logs/syslog files
So I used grep to sort them out:

```
cat syslog | grep "localhost postfix/smtp\["
```